# quartz TerracottaJobStore

Tags: quartz-scheduler, terracotta

I am using quartz scheduler with TerracottaJobStore Class for scheduling jobs at every 5 minutes . My job configurationd are :

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.terracotta.quartz.EnterpriseTerracottaJobStore
org.quartz.jobStore.tcConfigUrl = localhost:9510
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25

I am having a single job attached with 5000 triggers and then the job is scheduled.It takes 500ms to fire a single job (delay of 400ms and 100ms of thread switch approximation). It means in 1 sec two jobs are executing.With this case terracotta job store is firing 60 jobs per second which is fine for me. My issue is that the scheduled fire time for all jobs should be 1:30 as per after every 5 minutes of job time and scheduler is started at 1:25. Scheduled fire time of  jobs after 3000 number of jobs becomes 1:31 which should be 1:30 . I don't know why terracotta changes the  scheduled fire time of that jobs . Please help me in that.

Answer (score 1):

what is the Trigger you are using? This behaviour depends on type Trigger. From what I understand from the narration you should use DailyTimeIntervalTrigger.

Comment: Currently Using Cron Trigger.